# How does maven handle same jar with different group-id

Tags: java, maven

I am using different libraries that reference the same library in different versions with different group-ids (relocated). So maven assumes that those are different libraries and puts them both in classpath.

Nevertheless the package-names have not changed, so the same class with the same package-name exist in maven.

This is e.g. the case with org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14-1.38 vs. org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14-138. But since both versions are identical I don't expect trouble.

But with javax.xml.stream:stax-api-1.0-2 vs. stax:stax-api-1.0.1 we have no identical bytecode, so the same class with different content will be in the classpath.

Am I right - and if so, can maven warn me and prevent such problems?

Comment: Most IDE's have functionality to see all dependencies and their version.

Comment: But the IDEs won't warn if a given class exists in multiple jars on the classpath, so that really helps only when the problem is already known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the enforcer rule

https://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html

that allows you to break the build if a class name appears in more than one jar.

Comment: thanks, that worked (found no duplicated classes for bcmail and duplications for stax-api)

Answer (score 1):

No, for Maven those are different artifacts and you can get into trouble. Having multiple versions of the same class on the class path is not a good idea.

Comment: sure, but to prevent this I have to manually search the whole maven dependency-tree if some indirectly-referenced artifacts have the same name but different group-id

Comment: Yes, it is not supposed to happen (but it does). The Java module system solves the problem, but most projects are not using it yet.